# Plotting elements from shapefiles in R

Tags: r, plot, na, shapefile

stackoverflow community,

I have two shapefiles of the municipalities of Japan.  I'm using R to create separate plots for each of the municipalities.  I can make this work with one shapefile, but the identical syntax fails with the other.  Here are the code and the URLs for the data:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)

# Map A - this one works
# Please download: http://www.filefactory.com/file/z26nirxoz53/n/JPN_adm_zip

# Enter your path for readShapePoly
japanMapA = readShapePoly("JPN_adm/JPN_adm2")
names(japanMapA) 

plot(japanMapA[japanMapA$ID_2 == 1199,])

# Map B - this one doesn't work
# Please download: http://geocommons.com/overlays/173340.zip

# Again, enter your path for readShapePoly    
japanMapB = readShapePoly("japan_ver71") 
names(japanMapB)

plot(japanMapB[japanMapB$JCODE == 45382,])
```

The error it throws is:

```
Error in plot(japanMapB[japanMapB$JCODE == 45382, ]) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Error in japanMapB[japanMapB$JCODE == 45382, ] : 
NAs not permitted in row index
```

I don't know how to go about removing the NAs in this case, so I am unable to plot the individual elements.

Would greatly appreciate your help: have been banging my head against the wall for a while on this one!

Comment: `plot(japanMapB)` works, so my guess is something is funny with your selection. What is `JCODE` and why are you selecting on this variable to plot?

Comment: Something like: `plot(japanMapB[which(japanMapB$JCODE == 45382),])` seems to work to plot a section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this comes down to an issue with appropriate sub-setting.

Your `japanMapB` object consists of some metadata and a series of polygons for each shape stored in `japanMapB@polygons`. So, you have:

```
> length(japanMapB$JCODE)
#[1] 1902
> length(japanMapB@polygons)
#[1] 1902
```

As @PaulHiemstra notes though, you have some `NA` values in your `JCODE` variable

```
> table(is.na(japanMapB$JCODE))

#FALSE  TRUE 
# 1894     8
```

Which means you get NA results when trying to index the municipalities you want to plot.

```
> table(japanMapB$JCODE==45382,useNA="always")

#FALSE  TRUE  <NA> 
# 1893     1     8
```

Wrapping in `which` solves this:

```
which(japanMapB$JCODE == 45382)
#[1] 1802
#You will now select to plot only the 1802th polygon stored in the data object
plot(japanMapB[which(japanMapB$JCODE == 45382),])
```

Comment: Using `which` works perfectly.  Very grateful for your detailed response, @thelatemail, and for your points too, @PaulHiemstra: I have a much better understanding of how it's working now!

Answer (score 3):

What could be happening is that there are municipalities/polygons with an `NA` id. For example:

```
id = c(1,2,3,NA)
id == 2
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

Notice that with this comparison, `NA` values in `id` do not lead to `FALSE`, but to `NA`. Using `id == 2` for subsetting leads to the problem you see. @thelatemail wraps the call in `which`, which translates the logical vector to a set of indices where the logical vector is `TRUE`:

```
which(id == 2)
# [1] 3
```

Notice that the call to `which` eliminates the `NA`. This vector of indices can be safely used to subset. In general, you can use `na.omit` to remove `NA`'s:

```
l[l == 2]
# [1]  2 NA
l[na.omit(l == 2)]
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Yep - that's certainly the issue - you beat me to the punch as I was typing, but I have explained the specific situation for the OP in another answer.

Comment: As @thelatemail points out, yes, that was definitely the issue.  Many thanks to both for isolating and solving the problem!